# How to negotiate red5 connection parameters for streaming with JAVA

Tags: java, red5, rtmp, live-streaming

I have been creating a thin browser client (on java) that sends an RTMP stream to a specified red5 instance. I also use RTMP Researcher to monitor the traffic and events that occur between the client and the server.

Here is what I note:
There is obviously a map with options that is being exchanged between the red5 instance and the client. 
You can see it here:
[image] (direct link : http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/661/newbitmapimagelb.png )

What I am wondering about is is there a programmatic way to obtain this map in the client side and maybe change some of the parameters or just examine them

**Edit:**

I am connecting like this

`connect ( host, port, app, callback );`

. I assume I am sending some default parameters along, because the other connect methods have also an optionsMap as an argument. I was wondering what are the possible values that could be put in such an optionsMap and where to obtain a list of them?

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
I was also struggling with red5 and found this post. Download the red5 source and look inside this source file: [src/org/red5/server/net/rtmp/BaseRTMPClientHandler.java](http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/server/trunk/src/org/red5/server/net/rtmp/BaseRTMPClientHandler.java?r=4076)

You should know that the connect() method has multiple [signatures](http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/net/rtmp/RTMPClient.html).

The following method in BaseRTMPClientHandler.java creates the default parameters:

```
public Map<String, Object> makeDefaultConnectionParams(String server, int port, String application) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("app", application);
    params.put("objectEncoding", Integer.valueOf(0));
    params.put("fpad", Boolean.FALSE);
    params.put("flashVer", "WIN 9,0,115,0");
    params.put("audioCodecs", Integer.valueOf(1639));
    params.put("videoFunction", Integer.valueOf(1));
    params.put("pageUrl", null);
    params.put("path", application);
    params.put("capabilities", Integer.valueOf(15));
    params.put("swfUrl", null);
    params.put("videoCodecs", Integer.valueOf(252));
    return params;
}
```

Comment: I know that, however, i have been wondering where the list of another valid options is and how to obtain it. For example, videoCodecs, 252 is SVC. What would h264 be, etc..